# Calculate $27^{162} \pmod {41}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modules

Calculate: $27^{162} \pmod {41}$

So we need to calculate x which is a remainder of $$\frac{27^{162}}{41}$$

$27 = 3^3$ so we can write such equation:
$$3^{486} = 41k + x$$
or 
$$3^{3 \times 162} = 41k + x$$
where x is a reminder.

But what do I do next to calculate this without using calculator(or using simple one)?

Comment: Is the exponent 162 or 169?

Comment: 162 let me edit that quictly

Comment: $27^{40}=1$ modulo $41$ and $162=40\cdot4+2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fermat's Little theorem,
$$27^{40}\equiv1\pmod{41}$$
So,
$$(27^{40})^4\equiv1^4\equiv1\pmod{41}$$
Hence,
$$27^{162}=(27^{40})^4\times 27^2\equiv 27^2\pmod{41}$$

Comment: Oooo, thanks a lot, that's great

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Fermat's little theorem will be useful.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to apply it

Comment: $27^{40}\equiv1\bmod41$

Answer (score 0):

As $27=3^3,$

$$27^{162}=(3^3)^{162}=3^{486}$$

Now as $(3,41)=1$ and $\phi(41)=40,486\equiv6\pmod{\phi(41)}$

$$3^{486}\equiv3^6\pmod{41}\equiv(3^3)^2\equiv(-14)^2\equiv196\equiv-9\equiv32$$

Comment: What is $\phi(41)$? I mean what is $\phi()$

Comment: @Karol It is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$3^4 = 81 \equiv -1 \quad (\text{mod } 41) $$
so
$$3^{486} = (3^4)^{121}\cdot 3^2  \equiv (-1)^{121}\cdot 9 = -9 \equiv 32 \quad (\text{mod } 41) $$